# what web socket Uri should I use for phonegap chat application?

Tags: cordova, websocket, chat, messaging

I want to have an instant messaging service in a phonegap app. I am considering using web sockets for this. i was looking on websocket.org and tested their example code in my browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebSocket Test</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

  </script>

  <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>

  <div id="output"></div>
```

now i'm wondering when i do my own implementation, what wsUri I should use? I have my own domain and hosting with hostgator and i have asked them can i set up a websocket on my domain but they have said this is not possible because it is shared hosting.

I was also looking into kaazing.

[kaazing websocket-gateway editions](http://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/)
however the support told me that for a chat application i would need the enterprise edition as it has JMS. the enterprise edition seems like it would be very expensive and this is just starting off as a personal project so i couldnt afford it.

[kaazing pricing](https://kaazing.com/per-connection-pricing/)

Do you have any advice on the best and also cheapest way to connect to a web socket for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For users to access your service you need a machine with a public IP address where you can install the KWG.
The cheapest I know of is a cloud-based Linux machine, known as a Virtual Private Server.

Once you install the KWG, your client application can use an URI like this : 
ws://your.ip.address:someport/some.service.path
For example : 
ws://193.20.23.45:8000/jms

The configured URI is shown as an output when the Gateway starts.

For simple chat projects, you can create you own message routing logic in the backend, using KWG Community edition, which is free.

However, you will not be able to use Deluxe features available in Enterprise Editions, such as :
 - Load balancing and clustering for high availability
 - 24×7 worldwide enterprise support
 - Enterprise Shield
 - JMS support
 - Guaranteed delivery
 - Auto reconnect
And more.

As long as your project is not used in production, you can still use the Enterprise version of the Gateway, as the 100-connection limitation enough for this type of project.

Comment: thanks for your in-depth advice. i've accepted this as the answer. :)